# Selecting maximum value in a column based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two columns. ID and Percentage. Some IDs are not unique. Assume I have IDs 233, 233, 277, 277. And corresponding percentages: 4,5%, 7%, 3%, 1%. I need to select max. percentage for each ID. So that outcome is: 233 - 7%, 277 - 3%.

I wrote code that returns max value for the whole column, not the specific non-unique ID.

```
df['help_column'] = np.where(df.duplicated() ==True, max(df['percentage']),0)
```

As the highest value in the whole column is 33%, I get 33% for ID 233, and 33% for ID 277 instead of desired result. Thanks

Comment: You write "based on condition" in your title. What condition?

Comment: non-unique ID is a condition basically.

Answer (score 3):

This is more like a `transform`

```
df['help_column'] = df.groupby('ID')['percentage'].transform('max')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.groupby(['ID'])['percentage'].max()
```

Comment: This is good, but since it seems that OP wants a column for the max values that matches the ID column, using `transform` in WeNYoBen's answer is the way to go.