# Pandas get unique values of col1 which has max value in col3

Tags: pandas

My data looks something like this:

[image]

I am looking to get the unique values of col1 (which could have duplicates) and their corresponding max value in col3. I also need the col2 value of the row which has that max value.

I referred to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57595381/selecting-maximum-value-in-a-column-based-on-condition) but it's not quite giving me what I am looking for.
Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by find the max values and return new dataframe and then merge it with the first dataframe.

```
# initialize list of lists
data = [['a1','b1', 5], ['a1','b2', 6], ['c1', 'd1',3],['c1','d2', 4],['c1','d3', 1]]
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1','col2', 'col3'])
# Create dataframe from the max values
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['col1'])['col3'].max()).reset_index()
# Merge and return new dataframe
df1.merge(df2['col3'])
```